# Проблема в том, что: "Cтраница не может быть обслужена"

Tags: python, heroku

Мне выводит сообщение, что "В приложении произошла ошибка, и ваша страница не может быть обслужена. Если вы являетесь владельцем приложения, проверьте свои журналы для получения подробной информации. Вы можете сделать это из интерфейса командной строки Heroku с помощью команды..."

Но я в логах её не вижу!

````
2021-06-15T20:50:54.020743+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=discord-bot-faqq.herokuapp.com request_id=70944410-4a5d-4899-9790-17bd633450df fwd="194.24.191.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-15T20:50:54.273325+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=discord-bot-faqq.herokuapp.com request_id=0031036b-f987-4d86-8933-e827daad9646 fwd="194.24.191.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-15T20:54:11.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user robin.homenson@mail.ru
2021-06-15T20:54:41.375234+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user robin.homenson@mail.ru
2021-06-15T20:54:41.375234+00:00 app[api]: Deploy a0644099 by user robin.homenson@mail.ru
2021-06-15T20:54:52.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-06-15T20:55:07.678628+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=discord-bot-faqq.herokuapp.com request_id=f0f40719-1e9e-462f-99f3-974544fe26d6 fwd="194.24.191.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-15T20:55:07.934999+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=discord-bot-faqq.herokuapp.com request_id=a71e972f-aeba-45d6-87b0-610a6b3c2594 fwd="194.24.191.141" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-06-15T20:58:53.067905+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=discord-bot-faqq.herokuapp.com request_id=c0f2f869-0896-4cc1-bde8-e393a9a2a712 fwd="54.198.55.229" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https```
````

Answer (score 0):

Введите в терминале `heroku logs`
Или зайдите на сайте https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/ в свое приложение и нажмите More/view logs

Comment: Спасибо, но я всё-равно не могу найти ошибку. Вопрос дополнен

Comment: можете отправить структуру вашего проекта и желательно файлы setting.py, если это джанго как я полагаю

Comment: Я совсем ещё зелён в python и вообще в сфере, можно объяснить конкретнее то, что от меня требуется? (Это бот бля discord)

Comment: в Procfile что стоит web или worker? попробуйте на worker поменять

Comment: В данном файле стоит: worker